# how to create a file in application server with abap programing

Tags: abap

I have a file in my `D:` drive of my computer and I want to copy this file to an SAP application server so that I am able to see my file with transaction AL11.
I know that I can create a file with AL11 but I want do this in ABAP.

Of course in my search I find this code but I cannot solve my problem with it.

```
data: unixcom like   rlgrap-filename. 
data: begin of tabl occurs 500,

    line(400),

  end of tabl.

dir = 

unixcom = 'mkdir mydir'. "command to create dir

"to execute the unix command
call 'SYSTEM' id 'COMMAND' field unixcom
              id 'TAB'     field tabl[].
```

Comment: Use function module `ARCHIVFILE_CLIENT_TO_SERVER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CG3Z transaction and with this transaction I was able to copy a file in the application server directory.

Comment: Note that this transaction is only available in an ERP system.

Answer (score 1):

To upload the file to the application server, there are three steps to be followed. To open the file use the below statement:

Step1: OPEN DATASET file name FOR INPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT.

To write into the application server use.

Step2: TRANSFER name TO file name.

Dont forget to close the file once it is transferred.

Step3: CLOSE DATASET file name.

Plese mark with correct answer, if it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using ABAP you could create a small report that uses the function module `GUI_UPLOAD` to get the file from your local disk into an internal table and then write it to the application server with something like this:

```
lv_filename = '\\path\to\al11\directory\file.txt'.

OPEN DATASET lv_filename  FOR OUTPUT IN TEXT MODE ENCODING UTF-8.

LOOP AT lt_contents INTO lv_line.
  TRANSFER lv_line TO lv_filename.
ENDLOOP.

CLOSE DATASET lv_filename.
```

Comment: Why write any code at all when one could run simply the function module `ARCHIVFILE_CLIENT_TO_SERVER` in SE37?

Comment: @Jagger That would be a better solution for this particular question, indeed. But I did not know about this function module (thanks to you, now i do :-) ). Why don't you post that as an answer? I also think that the code in this answer still is useful.